# Can't find main Bundle plist

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, cocos2d-iphone, plist

I am trying to use the Facebook SDK. I need to add 3 key:values pairs to my info.plist. I can't find the info.plist in my files, I only found the main-Info.plist in the folder libs/external of my project but when I inserted there the key:values for the Facebook SDK it gave the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBAppBridge: AppID not found; Add a string valued key with the appropriate id named FacebookAppID to the bundle *.plist'
*** First throw call stack:
```

So I created a new file named Info.plist and added there the necessary information. After I done that I couldn't even build my app. What should I do?

Here is an images that shows all the *.plist files in my project:
[image]

I have the feeling that all the values that should be in my bundle .plist are here:
[image]
But I can't add new values here!! 
P.S. I created this project using spritebuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a project using SpriteBuilder a file Info.plist was created in the localization: "Source/Resources/info.plist". For some reason this file is not accessible on xcode I could only find it on the finder. I just had to add this file to XCode and edit it there and it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

the info.plist will be renamed based on the name of your app, it will beocome AppName-Info.plist.

You may have found the wrong one.  Undo those changes, and look for the AppName-Info.plist in the root of your xcode project.

Comment: I have updated my question to show all the *.plist files in my project. There is no AppName-Info.plist. Is it because I started the project using spritebuilder?